# Update cart when deleting item with AJAX not getting rid of item

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying delete an item from my cart, however, it will not disappear when I click on the delete button. I'm wondering what's happening, and was hoping someone could help me figure out what's going on. There is some back end code which I will not post because I feel it is working. It seems everything is working, but when I click the delete button, it will not remove the contents.

```
$(document).ready(function(data){

    load_cart_data();

    function load_cart_data()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "model/fetchcart.php",
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data){
                    $('#cart_items').html(data.cart_details);
                    $('.total_price').text(data.total_price);
                    $('.badge').text(data.total_item);
                }
            });
        }

    $('.purchase_add').click(function(){
        var product_id = $(this).attr("id");

        var product_name = $('#name'+product_id).val();

        var product_code = $('#code'+product_id).val();

        var product_price = $('#price'+product_id).val();  

        var product_quantity = $('#quantity'+product_id).val();

        var action = "add";

        if (product_quantity > 0) { // as in the value
            $.ajax({
                url: "model/action1.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    product_id:product_id,
                    product_name:product_name,
                    product_code:product_code,
                    product_price:product_price,
                    product_quantity:product_quantity,
                    action:action,
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    load_cart_data();
                    alert('Item has been added to cart');
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert('Please enter number of quantity');
        }
    });

        $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
        var button = $(this);
        var product_id = $(this).attr("id");
        var action = 'remove';
        if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this product")) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "model/action1.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                product_id: product_id,
                action: action
            },
            success: function() 
            {
                load_cart_data();
                button.parents('.shopping_cart_item').fadeOut('fast');
                $('#shopping_cart_item'+product_id).remove();
            }

        })
        } 
        else 
        {
    return false;
    } 
});
});
```

When I click the delete button, I DO receive feedback if I use an alert function, but the item won't unset itself. Neither the remove function, or the fadeOut function will remove the contents, and the SESSION will not unset like it seems as well.

This is a piece of my action file

```
if($_POST["action"] == 'remove')
 {
  foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
  {
   if($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]['product_id'] == $_POST["product_id"])
   {
    unset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]);
   }
  }
 }
```

and this is the data that is fetched from the load_cart_data() function

```
<div class="shopping_cart_item" id="shopping_cart_item'.$values['product_id'].'">

            <div class="shopping_cart_img"><img src="image/'.$values['product_code'].'.jpg"></div>

            <div class="shopping_cart_desc">

                <div class="shopping_cart_delete"><p>ET SPORK<span class="dash"> - </span>PREORDER<span class="dash"> -</span> 31%</p><div class="delete" id='.$values['product_id'].'>x</div></div>


                <p class="finish"><span>Finish:</span> <span>'.$values['product_name'].'</span></p>

                <div class="shopping_cart_number">
                    <input type="text" value='.$values['product_quantity'].'><span>x</span><span>'.$values['product_price'].'</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any help would be GREATLY APPRECIATED. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could replace the unset method because the documentation said this http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php:

> If a globalized variable is unset() inside of a function, only the local variable is destroyed. The variable in the calling environment will retain the same value as before unset() was called.

So, you can use this:

```
if($_POST["action"] === 'remove')
{
    $cart = $_SESSION["shopping_cart"];
    foreach($cart as $keys => $values)
    {
        if($value['product_id'] === $_POST["product_id"])
        {
            unset($cart[$keys]);
            break;
        }
    }
    $_SESSION["shopping_cart"] = $cart;
}
```

or

```
if($_POST["action"] === 'remove')
{
    foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)
    {
        if($value['product_id'] === $_POST["product_id"])
        {
            array_splice($_SESSION["shopping_cart"], $keys, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This examples are in the comments of documentation to remove session properties using unset and the register_globals is on.

```
unset($GLOBALS[_SESSION][$sessionVariableName]);
```

and

```
$variable = $_SESSION['variable'];
unset( $_SESSION['variable'], $variable );
```

Comment: Thank you, I have solved my issue, it turns out I misplaced a bracket.